# flutter web - horizontal singlechildscrollview cannot scroll with mouse click and drag

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-web, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallistview

I want to scroll the item in the row with click and drag.
when I tries to scroll though click and drag it does nothing..................................................................................................................

```
Container(
            height: 300,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: List.generate(
                
                   services.length, (index) => GalleryCard(index: index)),
          ),
        ),
          )
```

This is the gallery card class:

```
class GalleryCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const GalleryCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  _GalleryCardState createState() => _GalleryCardState();
}

class _GalleryCardState extends State<GalleryCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 300,
          width: 340,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              recentWorks[widget.index].image,
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share GalleryCard code?

Comment: Gallerycard code added

Comment: I copy your code without any changes and it is working fine

Comment: it work for mobile but not work in web

Answer (score 6):

here is an example of what worked for me regarding [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)

in main.dart I added this class

```
    class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
    PointerDeviceKind.touch,
    PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
    PointerDeviceKind.unknown,
  };
}
```

then inside of "MaterialApp" add this

```
scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below you can scroll through click and drag it, and even scroll with the mouse wheel

Use this Custom Class

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomScrollbarWithSingleChildScrollView extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController controller;
  final Widget child;
  final Axis scrollDirection;

  const CustomScrollbarWithSingleChildScrollView(
      {required this.controller,
      required this.child,
      required this.scrollDirection,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      child: Scrollbar(
        controller: controller,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: controller,
          scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
        PointerDeviceKind.unknown,
      };
}
```

usage of the above widget class

```
CustomScrollbarWithSingleChildScrollView(
            controller: con,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: List.generate(
                  services.length, (index) => GalleryCard(index: index)),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score -2):

initialize a TabController :

```
 ScrollController con = ScrollController();

Container(
        height: 300,
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Scrollbar(
               scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.top,
               controller:con,
               child:SingleChildScrollView(
                     controller : con,
                     scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                     child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: List.generate(
                                  services.length, (index) => GalleryCard(index: index),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

working like a charm.

Comment: This requires the user to click and drag on the scroll bar instead of scrolling by dragging items.

Comment: you can use the InkWell widget to make what you want happen, check this package and copy-paste the code of the inkwell, [link](https://github.com/Hamza-Shewa/collapsed_drawer/blob/main/lib/components/collapsed_drawer.dart.) and replace the animation controller with your own scroll controller and do what ever you want with it.